# SQL Server running a filecheck on a different server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, filepath, file-exists

I'm really bad at SQL and couldn't find anything near what I really need. I'm trying to create a Stored Procedure that should run each night to check if records in my database have an equivalent file on a server with all our data.

Example: Record with a mp4 has: [Spotnumber] -> 0000001. Then my procedure should check (not locally) if the file exists on the other server with this number.

Also the place where it should look could be fore exemple (not locally) C:/Spots. And in this directory there'll be subdirectories like: 2013, 2012, 2011. It should check in each directory if it doesn't exists.

For this I was thinking to make something like this: [Single check](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/30527/sql-server-how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-directory/). But this one searches locally and already has the url in a table-field. This won't be possible for mine.

So my question is: Is it even possible to do this with just a SQL procedure? If yes how should I make it check all the files on another server (what path should I use?) + How can I make it check for each record in each subdirectory?

Comment: It is, but it's a very bad idea. Databases are about storing and querying data, not running shell scripts. While you can execute shell commands, you would have to disable some security restrictions to do it, the performance would be bad and it would seriously hurt any other queries that ran at the same time. It's far easier to write a script in whatever language you prefer, pull the data from the server and then check for the files.

Comment: The purpose would be to just run this once each evening and by running this add a bit to the table if the file exists or isn't. And then that data would be used by a program later-on. So it would have been handy if I could just program it with a single stored-procedure. But I could indeed check for writing it as a script. but then again, how should my path look like to find the files on another server is it something like <ip>\c$\Spots?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another approach.

Instead of using Sql server to check if the file exists then update the db.

Why don't you use a powershell script checking if a file exist, then in this powershell script update the database. With a little search on google you can find all functions on microsoft blogs explaining how to check if a file exists and update file.

Another solution, you could create an assembly in your database with a .net language and work with that.

Last possibility, i think it can be possible too with SSRS.

If you really need to do that with tsql, you should allow xcmd command on your server, then use xcmd... but it means every body could use xcmd. It's not designed too and not suggested :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this elaborated answer. Like I told @PanagiotisKanavos I'll check if the powershell script would work in this project too. I'm on internship so I don't have much liberties ^^

Comment: *sigh* I can't even mark your answer as usefull answer to my own question as a new member of Stackoverflow...

Comment: I seriously doubt you can ask to remove the security restrictions from the database so that you can access the file system. It's a 'get-fired-for-suggesting' idea and the author of the article you provided should be treated accordingly

Comment: I don't see why we should lower the security of the database, because the stored procedure is on that db itself, it's the security for the "shared" directory on the server that should be lowered so that you can go check in it if the files exists.